# Search and Cut URL address

Tags: database, function, crm, filemaker

So lets say I have a thousand URLs in roughly the same format, but varied in length, something like below-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/asktitle<strike>?2482093480sdfsd</strike>

When all I need is "**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/asktitle**"

My question is, in filemaker, what would be the best way to create a calculation field, that trimmed all of the URLs down to just before the question mark, as shown above. I imagine I would somehow need to search the field for the "?" character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Left ( YourField ; Position ( YourField ; "?" ; 1 ; 1 ) - 1 )
```

Or:

```
GetValue ( Substitute ( YourField ; "?" ; ¶ ) ; 1 )
```